# How to filter by Date

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a dropdown that have 3 values (Status Values): *All, Active, Inactive* and a Table with results.

The dropdown will filter the table results by the status, this status depends on a field that is from Date value.

- **Active**: End_date is null. Returns the results that do not have a end_date
- **Inactive**: end_sate is not null. Returns the results that have a end_date
- **All**: will not query by nothing. Returns all results

Comment: There is no question here and there is no code either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first you need to create a parameter in your [query script](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_script) datasource:
[image: Query script parameter]

Once you have the parameter, you can bind it to dropdown's value and add the following code to the `onValueChange` event

```javascript
app.datasources.MyTableDatasource.load();
```

Your query script code will look similar to this:

```javascript
var status = query.parameters.Status;

switch(status) {
  case 'Active':
    query.filters.end_date._equals = null;
  break;

  case 'Inactive':
    query.filters.end_date._notEquals = null;
}

// we keep original query to preserve its paging and sorting settings
// and we do not set any additional filters in case selected status
// is not Active or Inactive
return query.run();
```

Comment: Hello @Pavel Shkleinik
Thanks for the response.
after all changes still got an error:
Executing query for datasource DRIVERS_LIST: (Error) : Cannot set property "_equals" of undefined to "null".
at datasources.DRIVERS_LIST.script:16
script:
var status = query.parameters.Status;
switch(status) {
  case 'Active':
    query.filters.end_date._equals = null;
  break;
  case 'Inactive':
    query.filters.end_date._notEquals = null;
  break;
  case 'All':
    query.clearFilters();
  break;
    
  default:
    query.filters.end_date._equals = null; 
}
return query.run();

Comment: Most likely you made a typo or didn't update field name here: `query.filters.<PutValidFieldNameHere>._equals = null;`

Comment: it worked out. Newbie error in here.

Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer to help other developers like you.